# Excel Message During Code(C#)

Tags: c#, winforms, excel, interop

When my code is running I have a messagebox popup from excel that has a retry I just want my code to be able to simulate hitting the enter key if it pops up which it does everytime. This is the Messagebox that come up and freezes my code.

[image]

I turned off one of them using the OLE message, but I still get this messagebox any way to simulate a click on retry or enter key,?

```
//Turn off OLE Error Message
oXL.DisplayAlerts = false;
```

Comment: If you step through your code, does it seem to pop this up at a certain line by chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[InputSimulator](http://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/) is a very flexible (and reliable) wrapper that is capable of simulating keyboard and mouse events.

It wraps SendInput under the hood but abstracts away all the PInvoke calls and other complexity.  It's a drop in DLL that (for your situation) should only take one line of code.

```
InputSimulator.SimulateKeyPress(VirtualKeyCode.ENTER);
```

Comment: that's pretty awesome I didn't even know this was possible. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can try sendkeys, to send a key stroke to the message box

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering if the problem is caused because you have a large loop that never makes use of the [`Application.DoEvents()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.doevents.aspx) call?  As for dismissing the message that seems like a poor way to handle the problem to me.